# Convergence conditions for an iterative scheme

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be a *singular* and symmetric matrix, with $\lambda_1=0$ and $\lambda_i >0$ for $i=2,\ldots,n$.
>
> Consider the iteration
>
> $$x^{*} = b- (A-I)x_k$$
> $$x_{k+1} = \alpha x^{*} +(1- \alpha)x_k$$
>
> Under which conditions on $x_0$, $\alpha$ and $b$, does it converge to the true solution of $Ax =b$?

---

I really can't move. I tried to compute $e_{k+1}$ but I couldn't find any useful relation. Also, I don't know how to find some constraints on $x_0$.

---

**EDIT**

I tried to follow @uranix comment's and I found: $$e_{k+1} = \alpha b + (I - \alpha A) x_k  -x $$

which I rewrite (using consistency) as $$e_{k+1} = (I-\alpha A)(x_k -x)=(I- \alpha A)e_{k}$$

Therefore $$e_{k+1} = (I-\alpha A)^k e_0$$

Now I would require the spectral radius to be less than $1$, but since $$\lambda(I -\alpha A)= 1-\lambda(A)$$ I have that the first eigenvalue is $1-\alpha \lambda_1=1-\alpha \cdot 0 = 1$

So I can't say anything about convergence... there must be another way. Indeed, I didn't use symmetry and also no conditions on $x_0$, as writen in the text

Comment: Perhaps a starting point is to determine _what_ $x_k$ should converge _to_. You can do this by assuming you have a fixed point in your iteration.

Comment: @snar I found that $x_k$ should converge to the solution of $Ax=b$, by consistency... I can't understand probably what you mean

Comment: Try to eliminate $x^*$ first. After that assuming $x_k \to z$ prove that $Az = b$ (that means if the sequence converges, it converges to the solution of $Ax = b$). Next, write $x_k = z + e_k$ and obtain the relation between $e_{k+1}$ and $e_k$. If everything is done right, the relation won't contain $b$, only $\alpha$ and $A$.

Comment: @uranix I just edited my question, but I am a bit confused on how to finish

Comment: Good. Due to matrix A is symmetrical its eigenvectors form a orthonormal basis: $A \phi_m = \lambda_m \phi_m, \quad (\phi_m, \phi_{m'}) = \delta_{mm'}$. Expand $e_k$ by the basis: $e_k = \sum_m c_{k,m} \phi_m$ and obtain the relation between $c_{k+1,m}$ and $c_{k,m}$. Since $\|e_k\|_2^2 = \sum_{m} c_{k,m}^2$ (Parseval's identity) the convergence condition $e_k \to 0$ is equivalent to $c_{k,m} \to 0$ for each $m$.

Comment: @uranix I understood you argument, but I have no clue on how to find some relation between the coefficients since I do not know anything about the eigenvectors

Comment: Checked your edit: the spectral radius condition really is necessary and sufficient for convergenc, but only in the case when no information about $x_0$ (in fact about $e_0$) is known a-priori. When you can restrict $e_0$ to some subspace (really rare case in practice) the convergence requirements may be relaxed.

Comment: @uranix Oh I see. I didn't know that. Btw, I can't use your last suggestion as I can't find any relation  between $c_{k+1},m$ and $c_{k,m}$

Comment: @uranix I expanded $e_k$ and found $$\sum_m c_{k+1,m} v_m  = (I-\alpha A) \sum_m c_{k,m} v_m$$

Now, I would obtain $$c_{k+1,m} I - c_{k,m} (I-\alpha A)=0 $$

but now I have no idea on how to conclude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little hint.

As I said in comments, consider the eigenvalue basis. The basis vectors are orthogonal and may be scaled to form an orthonormal basis:
$$
A \phi_m = \lambda_m \phi_m, \quad m = 1, \dots, m\\
(\phi_m, \phi_{m'}) = \delta_{mm'}.
$$

Expanding error vectors over the basis $e_k = \sum_{m=1}^n c_{k,m} \phi_m$ allows to rewrite convergence condition using expansion coefficients. Using Parseval's identity
$$
\|e_k\|_2^2 = \sum_{m} c_{k,m}^2
$$
we obtain that $e_k \to 0$ happens only if for all $m$ each coefficient converges to zero, that is
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} c_{k,m} = 0, \quad m = 1,\dots,n.
$$

Acting with $(I - \alpha A)^k$ on $e_0$ acts on each eigenvalue separately:
$$
e_k = (I - \alpha A)^k e_0 = (I - \alpha A)^k \sum_{m=1}^n c_{0,m} \phi_m = \\ =
\sum_{m=1}^n c_{0,m} (I - \alpha A)^k \phi_m = \sum_{m=1}^n c_{0,m} (1 - \alpha \lambda_m)^k \phi_m.
$$

Comparing the right hand side with $\sum_{m=1}^n c_{k,m} \phi_m$ we immediately get the relation
$$
c_{k,m} = (1 - \alpha \lambda_m)^k c_{0,m}.
$$

Now it's up to you to find the conditions when $\lim_{k \to \infty} c_{k,m} = 0$ for every $m = 1,\dots,n$.

Comment: thanks for the effort @uranix.


If $m \geq 2$, then the condition is $1- \alpha \lambda_m<1$ ,i.e. $-\alpha \lambda_m <0$ and since $\lambda_m>0$, I have the condition $\alpha>0$

Instead, if $m=1$, then I have $c_{1,k} =c_{0,m}$. Therefore I need  $c_{0,m}=0$


Is it correct, or am I still missing something?

Comment: True up to $|1 - \alpha \lambda_m| < 1$ instead of $1 - \alpha \lambda_m < 1$. This limits the maximal value of $\alpha$. $c_{0,1} = 0$ means that $e_0$ is orthogonal to $\phi_0$, that is $(x_0 - x, \phi_0) = 0$.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot the absolute value...

About $c_{0,1}$... why is it $(x_0-x, \phi_0)$? I mean, why the coefficients of the linear combinations have this form?

Comment: Oh okay,  every element of an Hilbert space can be written as linear combination of basis vectors with that coefficients, now I recall :)

Comment: So the conditions are: $e_0 \perp \varphi_0$ and $\alpha \in (0,\frac{2}{\lambda_m}]$ $(m \geq 2)$

Is there also a condition on the r.h.s $b$ ?

Comment: $e_0$ is related to $b$: $e_0 = x_0 - x = x_0 - A^{-1} b$

Comment: But $A$ ìs singular @uranix 

Maybe I can use $b - Ax_0 = A e_0$...

Comment: Oh, missed that. Then $Ax=b$ is solvable only when $b \bot \phi_1$. And in that case there are infinitely many solutions that differ by $\beta \phi_1$. The numerical solution converges to $x \bot \phi_1$ (due to $c_{k, 1} = 0$)

Comment: Sorry for the last time, but how did you find $b \perp \phi_1$ ? I think you used the relation in my previous comment, something like $$(b-A e_0, \phi_1) = (b, \phi_1) + (A e_0, \phi_1)$$

but I can't understand how the last term goes to $0$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111921/discussion-between-uranix-and-andereben).